# Priority of equality and conditional operators in java

Tags: java, operators

I run the following code snippet

```
System.out.println(T1() ? F1() : T2() == T3() ? F2() : T4());
public static boolean T1() { System.out.println("true1"); return true; }
public static boolean T2() { System.out.println("true2"); return true; }
public static boolean T3() { System.out.println("true3"); return true; }
public static boolean T4() { System.out.println("true4"); return true; }
public static boolean F1() { System.out.println("false1"); return false; }
public static boolean F2() { System.out.println("false2"); return false; }
```

I get the output

```
true1
false1
false
```

The first ternary operator been evaluated **before** evaluating the equality operator, but according to [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), equality operator has greater priority than the ternary one, therefore the equality operator must be evaluated before the ternary one.

Whats the reason of such code behavior?

Comment: It looks to me like the code was evaluated as if it was `T1() ? F1() : (T2() == T3() ? F2() : T4())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand what priority means. The fact that == has higher priority than the ternary operator does not mean that in an expression all == subexpressions are evaluated first. Priority is solely a means to omit parentheses in certain cases.

For example, the expression

```
a == b ? c : d
```

could be equivalent to either `(a==b) ? c : d` or `a == (b ? c : d)`. The fact that == has higher priority means that it is actually equivalent to the first.

In the expression

```
a ? b : c == d
```

there is no ambiguity, it is always equivalent to `a ? b : (c == d)`. Since the ternary operator is lazily evaluated, if `a` holds, `c == d` is never evaluated.

Comment: as u said, we can omit parentheses in some cases, so, why isn't the same situation here?
`(a?b:c) == (d?f:g)` or `(a?b:(c==d?f:g))`. Why does the higher priority of `==` is not working here?

Comment: @user1448906 Well, since == has higher priority, `a ? b : c == d ? f : g` is equivalent to `a ? b : (c == d) ? f : g`, because the ternary operator is right-associative this in turn is equivalent to `a ? b : ((c == d) ? f : g)`.

Answer (score 7):

[JLS 15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

> The conditional operator is syntactically right-associative (it groups right-to-left). Thus, a?b:c?d:e?f:g means the same as a?b:(c?d:(e?f:g)).

And in your case :

```
T1() ? F1() : (T2() == T3() ? F2() : T4())
  a     b            c         d       e
```

`T1()` is evaluated true, returning true, so only `F1()` is evaluated next.

Answer (score 0):

The `T2() == T3()` is never evaluated. Your code is equal to:

```
if(T1()) {
  System.out.println(F1());
}
else {
  if(T2() == T3()) {
    System.out.println(F2());
  }
  else {
    System.out.println(T4());
  }
}
```

Here you clearly see why it is never evaluated - because `T1()` is true and the `else` block is never entered.